# Module 'image picker' not found

Tags: android, ios, flutter, plugins, imagepicker

I am trying to run my flutter app that has the image picker plugin on iPad, but I get this error. Both android and ios emulator works fine, even real android tablet is working too. I have tried all of the suggestions that I could find about this error, but non of that worked for me.
Any suggestions?

pubspec:

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  swipe_refresh: ^1.0.1
  json_annotation: any
  flutter_phoenix: ^1.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.3+2
```

The file that has the error:

```
//
//  Generated file. Do not edit.
//

#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

#if __has_include(<image_picker/FLTImagePickerPlugin.h>)
#import <image_picker/FLTImagePickerPlugin.h>
#else
@import image_picker;  --------- error: Module 'image_picker' not found
#endif

#if __has_include(<shared_preferences/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h>)
#import <shared_preferences/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h>
#else
@import shared_preferences;
#endif

@implementation GeneratedPluginRegistrant

+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry {
  [FLTImagePickerPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTImagePickerPlugin"]];
  [FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin"]];
}

@end
```

Comment: could you show some code / pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?